# Total time uploaded by a channel on YouTube

Tags: youtube

Is there a way to know the total time of all the videos uploaded by a channel on YouTube without manually counting and calculating?

In my specific case I want to know the total hours it would take to watch all the 182 videos (with variable lengths) in a channel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply go to the videos tab and in the top left of that tab it usually has a header that says uploads, next to that there should be a button saying play all. If you click that it should make a playlist of all of the youtubers channel.

Answer (score 3):

I do not believe there is a *simple* way to do this. Maybe there is a third party statistics website that could help you, though the ones I know of do not have that particular statistic.

The best suggestion I have for you is to put them all in a playlist, and YouTube will tell you how long all of the videos are together. I'd suggest temporarily clearing your Watch Later playlist, maybe making a copy first, and hit the watch later button on all of the thumbnails of the videos. Of course, do this in a logical manner; sort the videos by date uploaded or something. Once you have them all in a playlist, you can simply go to your list of playlists and read the time. Hope that works for you. I could not think of anything better...